# Tikz-UML not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I would like to draw diagrams with the `tikz-uml` package. I downloaded the `tikz-uml.sty` file from http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en and put it in the same folder as my `test.tex` file. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen,xstring,calc,pgfkeys,pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \umlactor[x=-1]{A}
   \umlactor[x=1]{B} 
   %\umlassoc{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with PDF-LaTeX in TeXLive 2015 with TeXShop (v3.61) works.
When I attempt to draw an `tikz-uml`-specific arrow between the nodes A and B by omitting the `%` symbol in line 10

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \umlactor[x=-1]{A}
   \umlactor[x=1]{B} 
   \umlassoc{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following error message:

```
./test.tex:12 Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@
l.12    \umlassoc{A}{B}
?
```

I recently updated via TeX Live Utility (v1.23). I remember that it worked before. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Was someone able to reproduce the error?

Comment: The only solution I found was to switch back to TeXLive-2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [page you linked](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en) is a new version [tikzuml-v1.0 (29 March 2016)](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/src/tikzuml-v1.0-2016-03-29.tbz)

I tried your example and received:

[image]

The `\umlassoc{A}{B}` creates the line between the two figures, there is no error in my TeXLive-installation 2015.

It seems the problem is solved in meantime.

Comment: Ah, great! Now it works.

Comment: how is it that it is not on CTAN?