# How to upload tikz-uml package on TeXstudio

Tags: tikz-uml

I cannot run my code. I keep receiving this message:

[image]

I have tried to install the latest `tikz-uml` package  but I didn't succeed.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{Schedule}
\umlusecase[x=-3]{Check Request}
\umlusecase[x=3]{Ask Constraints}
\umlusecase[x=-2,y=-2]{Deny Request}
\umlusecase[x=3, y=-2]{Collect Constraints}
\umlusecase[x=-3,y=-4]{Determine Schedule}
\umlusecase[x=3,y=-4]{Merge Constraints} 
\umlusecase[y=-6]{Resolve Conflicts}
\end{umlsystem}

\umlactor[x=-8]{Initiator}
\umlactor[x=-8,y=-6]{Participant A}
\umlactor[x=8]{Participant B}
\umlactor[x=8,y=-6]{Conflict Resolver} 

\umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-3}
\umlassoc{Participant A}{usecase-5}
\umlassoc{Participant B}{usecase-2}
\umlassoc{Participant B}{usecase-4}
\umlassoc{Conflict Resolver}{usecase-7}

\umlextend{usecase-2}{usecase-3}
\umlinclude{usecase-5}{usecase-7}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example of Use case diagram using tikz-uml. Examlpe from the book Requirements Engineering by Axel van Lamsweerde.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is ```pdflatex``` installed?

Comment: I really don't know how and where to check that

Comment: Open command line application `cmd` and try ```pdftex --version``` or ```pdflatex --version```. Provide the output here. The command will print the information whether ```pdflatex``` is installed or not. It would aslo print the name and version of TeX binaries (if installed).

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32>pdftex --version
pdftex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7439 (1.40.21) (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2020 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010`

Comment: ```pdflatex``` is installed in your OS. Check the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299183/tikz-uml-not-working). Could you reinstall the package and compile again?

Comment: not working still

Comment: Keep the ```tikz-uml.sty``` file in your working directory and try to compile using ``pdflatex``.