tikz-uml on overleaf `tikz-uml.sty' not found
I use overleaf but I cannot compile this code which does not contain any errors.
The error that overleaf gives me is : LaTeX Error: File `tikz-uml.sty' not found.
\documentclass[12pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{Schedule}
\umlusecase[x=-3]{Check Request}
\umlusecase[x=3]{Ask Constraints}
\umlusecase[x=-2,y=-2]{Deny Request}
\umlusecase[x=3, y=-2]{Collect Constraints}
\umlusecase[x=-3,y=-4]{Determine Schedule}
\umlusecase[x=3,y=-4]{Merge Constraints} 
\umlusecase[y=-6]{Resolve Conflicts}
\end{umlsystem}

\umlactor[x=-8]{Initiator}
\umlactor[x=-8,y=-6]{Participant A}
\umlactor[x=8]{Participant B}
\umlactor[x=8,y=-6]{Conflict Resolver} 

\umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Initiator}{usecase-3}
\umlassoc{Participant A}{usecase-5}
\umlassoc{Participant B}{usecase-2}
\umlassoc{Participant B}{usecase-4}
\umlassoc{Conflict Resolver}{usecase-7}

\umlextend{usecase-2}{usecase-3}
\umlinclude{usecase-5}{usecase-7}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example of Use case diagram using tikz-uml. Examlpe from the book Requirements Engineering by Axel van Lamsweerde.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


there is no tikz-uml.sty in texlive, if you have such a file, where did you obtain it?

Here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547165/how-to-upload-tikz-uml-package-on-texstudio
I just realized that its author also couldn't compile it

so in case the above don't make it clear you need to copy tikz-uml.sty from your local machine in to your overleaf project, just as previously you must have copied it from somewhere on the web to your local machine.

Thanks, it works
